# launching VS2008 build from python

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-2008, build-automation

if I paste this into the command prompt by hand, it works, but if I run it from python, I get `The filename, directgory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`.

```
os.system('%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86')
os.system('devenv Immersica.sln /rebuild Debug /Out last-build.txt')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the backslashes are messing you up.  You need to use an R string (raw)

r"string"

See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals for reference

Comment: how about an up vote, since i answered the question :)